# How to do "or" operation in kernel function in cuda?

Tags: cuda

I am trying to use cuda to find if there is any non-zero element in arrays. But my code always give me `true` as output, even I put all zeros element as input. It seems I use the `||` operator in a wrong way. Could you give me some help?

`a0` is the input bool array with 16 elements.

`r0` is the output with 4 elements. (it always gives 1*4)

`Nc` is 4.

```
__global__ void boolTarget(int N, int Nc, bool * a0, bool* r0) 
{
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    while(idx<Nc)
    {
        bool * base = a0+idx*4;
        bool tmp;
        for(int i = 0;i<N;i++)
        {
            tmp = (*(base+i) || tmp);
        }
        r0[idx] = tmp;

        idx += blockDim.x*gridDim.x;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't initialize `tmp`.

Comment: @BlameTheBits Thank you. I am sorry for such idot problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `or` operator is `||`, so this is right.

Anyway, you must initialize `tmp` to false:

```
bool tmp = false;
```